# Font Awesome Upgrading to 4.0.3

Tags: font-awesome-4

I am currently running 3.0.2 and looking into upgrading to 4.0.3. If we do go forward with the upgrade, will I have to go into all of the html and change the calls i currently have for the icons? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a couple of examples of the calls you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to, but there might only be small changes to continue using font awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There were some pretty significant changes from 3.x to 4.x.

The biggest change is that, instead of being `icon-*`, everything is now `fa fa-*`. (2 CSS classes - this is because it makes things easier on the CSS engine, enough to make a noticeable improvement in page rendering times.) However, there were also a number of renames and other small changes.

Full migration guide is available at https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4